# Replacing column names with another data frame if matches

Tags: r, multiple-columns

Hi I am looking into figuring out how to match data frames together by column, then renaming it. If there is no name that matches, then I would want to drop that column instead.

For example, I would use this main dataset, call it DF1:

| Name | Reference | Good | Fair | Bad | Great | Poor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Hill | 34 | 21 | 33 | 21 | 32 |
| Frank | Stairs | 29 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 29 |
| Bertha | Trail | 25 | 25 | 24 | 21 | 26 |

Then another DF, call this DF2, that allows me to replace the names of the columns of DF1

| Name | Adjusted_Name |
| --- | --- |
| Good | good_run |
| Great | very_great_work |
| Bad | bad run |
| Fair | fair run decent |

Essentially, the words that would be substituted would not be any pattern of any sort, and I would try to match this first column in DF2 and match to DF1, and if there is a match in DF2$Name and DF(whatever column), then I would replace that name with the same row of DF2$Adjusted_Name. If there is no match, then the value in DF1 is dropped.

So the final goal would be to achieve:

| Name | Reference | good_run | fair run decent | Bad run | very_great_work |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| George | Hill | 34 | 21 | 33 | 21 |
| Frank | Stairs | 29 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| Bertha | Trail | 25 | 25 | 24 | 21 |

In this case, "poor" was dropped because it didnt match the column name of DF1.

How should I go about this? How would I account if there thousands of columns? Does that change anything in how i Code? I am a bit new to R, and would appreciate any tips. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to a `tidyverse` solution, you could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>% 
  rename_with(~deframe(df2)[.x], .cols = df2$Name) %>% 
  select(Name, Reference, any_of(df2$Adjusted_Name))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Name   Reference good_run very_great_work bad_run fair_run_decent
  <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>
1 George Hill            34              21      33              21
2 Frank  Stairs          29              30      29              28
3 Bertha Trail           25              21      24              25
```

### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Name = c("George", "Frank", "Bertha"), Reference = c("Hill", 
"Stairs", "Trail"), Good = c(34, 29, 25), Fair = c(21, 28, 25
), Bad = c(33, 29, 24), Great = c(21, 30, 21), Poor = c(32, 29, 
26)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Reference = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Good = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Fair = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Bad = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Great = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Poor = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("Good", "Great", "Bad", "Fair"), Adjusted_Name = c("good_run", 
"very_great_work", "bad_run", "fair_run_decent")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Adjusted_Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: When I run, I get the error:

Error in select(., Name, Reference, any_of(df2$Adjusted_Name)) : 
  unused arguments (Name, Reference, any_of(df2$Adjusted_Name))

What would this mean?

Comment: Are you using the code with the data shown above? Are you using any other packages (like `plyr` or something)?

Comment: I am using the same code you have provided

Comment: What's your `dplyr` version? Please type `packageVersion("dplyr")`. Are you using any other packages?

Comment: It came out as [1] ‘1.0.8’

I think that is the only one I am using. Can results be affected if other packages are installed?

Comment: Other installed packages don't interfere unless they are loaded. That's odd, since I used the code (and data) shown above to create the output. 

Comment: I restarted R and my computer, and it works now?? I am very confused why it didnt work earlier, but thank you for your help!!!

Comment: A very random question but say if a column cannot be found, is there a way to drop it?

Comment: `select()` allows you to choose the columns that are shown. `any_of()` just selects the columns from it's argument that exists. Such a mechanic is used in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following - using the list of adjusted names, you can `grep` the list of desired words against column names and subset the data frame on it:

Data

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Name    Reference   Good    Fair    Bad Great   Poor
                 George Hill    34  21  33  21  32
                 Frank  Stairs  29  28  29  30  29
                 Bertha Trail   25  25  24  21  26")

adj_name <- c("good_run","very_great_run","bad run","fair run decent")
```

Index the columns based on `grep` from the string of desired names (note the `tolower()` on the column names as well)

```
desired_words <- paste(unlist(strsplit(adj_name, "_| ")), collapse = "|")

df[,c(1:2,grep(desired_words, tolower(names(df))))]
```

Output

```
#    Name Reference Good Fair Bad Great
#1 George      Hill   34   21  33    21
#2  Frank    Stairs   29   28  29    30
#3 Bertha     Trail   25   25  24    21
```